# how to allocate an array with size of 50,000,000 long int numbers

Tags: c++, c

I have a text file in which of its line, there is two numbers. each of them are nodes of a graph. the size of the file is 1.5 gb and had has 92522018 lines. the wanted thing is the node with maximum number of edges.

i need the the array for solving this problem.

is there any way to allocate this size of array or even bigger?

Comment: Use `std::vector<int>`.

Comment: @komeilsh 50,000,000 ints take 47mb of RAM. Are you seriously that short on RAM?

Comment: If you are in lack of RAM then you have to figure out a way of processing your data without holding it all in memory, i.e use streaming.

Comment: @JustSid: Check your math, an `int` or `long int` is larger than 1 byte ;)

Comment: You will be fine if you allocate your array on the heap but it most likely will not work on the stack because the default stack size will most likely be smaller than the size of this array.

Comment: @Blastfurnace What a weird machine you are on... :p Nah, you right, my bad. But still, 190mb... It's 2013, that really shouldn't do anything at all in terms of memory footprint.

Comment: Will your algorithm not work if you just give it chunks of data instead of everything all at once?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For C,

Use [malloc](http://www.codingunit.com/c-tutorial-the-functions-malloc-and-free)

For C++,

Use [Vectors](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/)

Answer (score 3):

You need dynamic allocation. In C, you can use [`malloc`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malloc). In C++, [`vectors`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_container_%28C%2B%2B%29) can be used for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Don't allocate the array in the stack use dynamic allocation

Comment: using stack memory doesn't really require the programmer to explicitly allocate memory for it, so the question sort of implies the OP is aware of this...

Answer (score 0):

In C++ you could use an `std::vector` for this problem

```
unsigned long int a, b;
std::vector<int> degree;
while (fscanf(f, "%li %li", &a, &b) == 2) {
    while (a >= degree.size() || b >= degree.size()) {
        degree.push_back(0);
    }
    degree[a]++; degree[b]++;
}
```

if you know in advance the number of nodes then just preallocate it

```
std::vector<int> degree(number_of_nodes);
while (fscanf(f, "%li %li", &a, &b) == 2) {
    degree[a]++; degree[b]++;
}
```

Comment: You can probably improve the performance by finding the max of `a` and `b` and only resizing to that. This will reduce double resizings if `b` > `a`.

Comment: @Dancrumb: ok. Actually for the pathological case of data sorted increasing on `a` it would be better to write a loop with `push_back` as that's guaranteed to work in amortized constant time. Resizing with `size()+1` formally doesn't provide such a guarantee.

Comment: Normally I wouldn't nitpick, but since the OP is talking 9 million lines, it would start to add up; nice change, btw!